# Do we have to calculate time for declaring statement in RAM model?

Tags: time-complexity, runtime-analysis, computation-models

Do we have to calculate time for declaring statement, in my case `int num3` statement. The following question was asked by professor as a post-lecture quiz. I selected `t(n)=3`, but the correct answer was `t(n)=4`.

```
What is the time taken by following algorithm on RAM model ?
```

[image]

```
t(n)=3
t(n)=4
t(n)=5
None of the above
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no standard answer, so you'll have to go by whatever convention is used in your course.